# "Creating Apps in Kivy" openweathermap API Key Error

Tags: windows, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

That's my first stackoverflow question.

I started with kivy and bought the book "Crating Apps in Kivy" from Dusty Phillips and all went well till he got to the openweatherapp chapter. (Which after a search other users had problems too...)
There you use the Openweather API to search for a location with a button and it should print the results in a list.

It's not the original code anymore. Others pointed out that the Link to the website changed, you have to use the API key. Of course I linked it correctly, I just typed "myAPIKey" here so it's not accesssable. The JSOn File on the bottom is what the site prints!

Also, the book formated cities in found location like that: d['name], d['sys']['country'] which I guess was also wrong, maybe the site changed here too?

My problem is that the UrlRequest from kivy doesn't seem to load anything. Or the iteration in found location is wrong, I don't know. It always says "KeyError: city" And I guess it's because it doesn't read it correctly at all. I tried a different approach with the python class requests - and it works perfectly fine! But I still want to know why this solution doesn't work.

My Questions: Where is my error with the json iteration? I have really problems with understanding because I'm also new to python.

Also: Why is request in the methode head? Where is it used?

Here the code from the book (I hope everything is typed correctly. If there is still an error with variables please point it out but I typed the code multiple times - my problem will probably be somewhere else...):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()

    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=myAPIKey=" + "{}"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        cities = ["{} ({})".format(d["city"]["name"], d["city"]["country"])for d in data["list"]]
        self.search_results.item_strings = cities
```

KV File:

```
AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    search_input: search_box
    search_results: search_results_list

    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
            size_hint_x: 25
    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        item_strings: []
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "city": {
        "id": 2761369,
        "name": "Vienna",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 16.37208,
            "lat": 48.208488
        },
        "country": "AT",
        "population": 0
    },
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0098,
    "cnt": 7,
    "list": [{
        "dt": 1476439200,
        "temp": {
            "day": 285.58,
            "min": 283.71,
            "max": 285.58,
            "night": 283.71,
            "eve": 285.43,
            "morn": 285.58
        },
        "pressure": 985.46,
        "humidity": 73,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }],
        "speed": 7.16,
        "deg": 154,
        "clouds": 0
    }, {
        "dt": 1476525600,
        "temp": {
            "day": 287.33,
            "min": 282.7,
            "max": 291.08,
            "night": 285.72,
            "eve": 291.01,
            "morn": 283.35
        },
        "pressure": 983.21,
        "humidity": 71,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 4.51,
        "deg": 150,
        "clouds": 32,
        "rain": 0.23
    }, {
        "dt": 1476612000,
        "temp": {
            "day": 286.88,
            "min": 283.94,
            "max": 287.15,
            "night": 283.94,
            "eve": 286.44,
            "morn": 286.26
        },
        "pressure": 989.94,
        "humidity": 98,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 501,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "moderate rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 4.36,
        "deg": 315,
        "clouds": 92,
        "rain": 5.51
    }, {
        "dt": 1476698400,
        "temp": {
            "day": 287.39,
            "min": 283.49,
            "max": 287.39,
            "night": 284.89,
            "eve": 285.05,
            "morn": 283.49
        },
        "pressure": 984.76,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 1.64,
        "deg": 132,
        "clouds": 69,
        "rain": 1.55
    }, {
        "dt": 1476784800,
        "temp": {
            "day": 285.91,
            "min": 283.52,
            "max": 285.91,
            "night": 283.52,
            "eve": 284.45,
            "morn": 284.18
        },
        "pressure": 982.64,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 3.23,
        "deg": 137,
        "clouds": 81,
        "rain": 2.4
    }, {
        "dt": 1476871200,
        "temp": {
            "day": 283.71,
            "min": 282.37,
            "max": 283.71,
            "night": 282.37,
            "eve": 282.52,
            "morn": 282.59
        },
        "pressure": 978.26,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 502,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "heavy intensity rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 2.68,
        "deg": 128,
        "clouds": 96,
        "rain": 14.37
    }, {
        "dt": 1476957600,
        "temp": {
            "day": 286.52,
            "min": 282.13,
            "max": 286.52,
            "night": 282.13,
            "eve": 282.72,
            "morn": 282.19
        },
        "pressure": 975.05,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }],
        "speed": 1.47,
        "deg": 173,
        "clouds": 13,
        "rain": 2.83
    }]
}
```

Btw, it's not a duplicate from [how do i use json api in my kivy program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914680/how-do-i-use-json-api-in-my-kivy-program) becaue it didn't really help... The code doesn't work anymore because the API changed.

(If anyone finds this question and is looking for a working URL reader, here is my code. Don't forget to import requests)

```
  def search_location(self):
        #Get URL From Weather API + Input
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID='enteryourweatherAPIKeyhere'&q=" + "{}"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        #Reads the Website and saves it in a string
        urlresults = (requests.get(search_url)).text
        #Converts Json to Python Dictionary
        urlresults = json.loads(urlresults)
        cities = ["{} ({})".format(urlresults["city"]["name"], urlresults["city"]["country"])]
```

Comment: Edit it here in case someone else made this mistake too: Searched for hours just to find out that i missed [] arround cities to make it a single list item. Oh man. That solves at least my List Problem.

Comment: But you still have a problem, right? Can you edit your question so that only things regarding your problem remain?

Comment: Done. It didn't changed much though, I just removed one question and added the [] around the cities variable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page:
http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401

the API now requires a key. After registering on openweathermap, a key will be mailed to you. Replace the current URL with the one given in the mail.

This worked for me.